# How can I add remove button to remove from DOM and Array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dom

This is my code

I want to add a function which makes a button to remove a contact from DOM and its object from array

also I want it to have "contact" class

also I want it to be added by only javascript
I have tried many ways but i could not solve it

this my whole code with all details to be understood better
Thank you all

it only has html and script

I will add css at the end

```
<body>
    <label for="name">
        Name :
    </label>
    <input id="name" type="text" />
    <br />
    <label for="number">
        Number :
    </label>
    <input id="number" type="number" />
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="send-btn">Add</button>
    <hr />
    <input type="text" id="search" />
    <button type="button" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
    <div id='container'></div>
    <script>
        const name = document.getElementById("name");
        const number = document.getElementById('number');
        const container = document.getElementById("container");
        const sendBtn = document.getElementById("send-btn");

        let searchInput = document.getElementById("search");
        const searchBtn = document.getElementById("searchBtn");
        let id = 0;
        const contacts = [];

        function ContactMaker(id, name, number) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number;
        }


        sendBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const newContact = new ContactMaker(id, name.value, number.value);
            id++;
            contacts.push(newContact);
            name.value = '';
            number.value = '';
            addToDOM();
        })


        searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            displayError();
            const found = contacts.find(item => item.name === searchInput.value);
            container.innerHTML += `name : ${found.name} <br/> number : ${found.number} <br/>`;
            searchInput.value = '';
        })


        function addToDOM() {
            const showContact = contacts.map(({
                id,
                name,
                number
            }) => `<div class = "contact">
<span> id : ${id} </span>
<br/>
<span> name : ${name} </span>
<br/>
<span> number : ${number} </span>

 
                  </div> <hr/>`).join('');

            container.innerHTML = `<div class = "contact-container"> ${showContact}</div>`;
        }


        function displayError() {
            if (searchInput.value === '' ||
                searchInput.value === null ||
                searchInput.value === undefined ||
                searchInput.value === " "
            ) {
                alert("Contact is NOT valid or NOT found ");
            }
        }
        
        console.log(contacts);

    </script>
</body>
```

thanks again

Comment: Plz, share your HTML/CSS!

Comment: it gave error while sending but i will try again

Comment: Sending where?..

Comment: its added now .... can u plz help?

Comment: So you need a button that will delete the contact...

Comment: Also if there is css then plz add it

Comment: yeah I want each contact has an delete button that when it is clicked on button ... its contact get deleted

Comment: the only css `* {
            font-family: cursive;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #remove-contact {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .contact {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: baseline;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 200px;
            border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 8px;
        }

        .contact span {
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was a little busy... I have added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
const name = document.getElementById("name");
const number = document.getElementById("number");
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const sendBtn = document.getElementById("send-btn");

let searchInput = document.getElementById("search");
const searchBtn = document.getElementById("searchBtn");
let id = 0;
const contacts = [];

function ContactMaker(id, name, number) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.number = number;
}

sendBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const newContact = new ContactMaker(id, name.value, number.value);
  id++;
  contacts.push(newContact);
  name.value = "";
  number.value = "";
  addToDOM();
});

searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  displayError();
  const found = contacts.find((item) => item.name === searchInput.value);
  container.innerHTML += `name : ${found.name} <br/> number : ${found.number} <br/>`;
  searchInput.value = "";
});

function addToDOM() {
  const showContact = contacts
    .map(
      ({
        id,
        name,
        number
      }) => `<div class = "contact">
<span> id : ${id} </span>
<br/>
<span> name : ${name} </span>
<br/>
<span> number : ${number} </span>
<button class="deleteBtn" id="deleteBtn${id}"> Delete ⚡</button>
</div> <hr/>
`
    )
    .join("");

  container.innerHTML = `<div class = "contact-container"> ${showContact}</div>`;
}

function displayError() {
  if (
    searchInput.value === "" ||
    searchInput.value === null ||
    searchInput.value === undefined ||
    searchInput.value === " "
  ) {
    alert("Contact is NOT valid or NOT found ");
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains("deleteBtn")) {
    const index = Number(e.target.id.slice(-1));

    if (contacts.length !== 1) {
      contacts.splice(index, 1);
      addToDOM();
    } else container.innerHTML = "";
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: cursive;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

#remove-contact {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.contact span {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<label for="name">Name :</label>
<input id="name" type="text" />
<br />
<label for="number">Number :</label>
<input id="number" type="number" />
<br />
<button type="button" id="send-btn">Add</button>
<hr />
<input type="text" id="search" />
<button type="button" id="searchBtn">Search</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thaaaaaannnnkkk you bro :))))

Comment: @James ... ✌